# Favourite Tags with Negation

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have both `java` and `android` listed in my favourite tags as I like answering questions for both.

However sometimes I just want to see the newest Java questions, which I would usually do by clicking the tag in my favourites list. Unfortunately all the questions that are tagged as Android *and* Java obscure the pure Java ones I feel like answering.

Is there any way to have a favourite tag work in the same way as the search feature so I could provide `[java] -[android]` to just show the Java questions easily?

Comment: You could just seach `[java] -[android]`. It's not a simple as a one-click, but I wouldn't call it complicated.

Comment: @Jim That's what I'm currently doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do it with the favorite tags, but if you look at the bottom of a search page, such as [[java] -[android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+-android), you will notice there is a feed icon. You can use that to find all the [newest questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java+-android&sort=newest) [java](/questions/tagged/java), but not [android](/questions/tagged/android).

[image: screenshot]